# TYPO3 Extbase Controller with new/createAction not showing form data after invalid validation

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I am trying to create an Extbase extension in TYPO3 10.4 which fetches and inserts records from an external API. I've got most of it working, but am stuck on one thing. I'm converting the data I'm getting from the API to DTO models and also use those when creating a new record for the API. Just like I'd do with models created from/for database records I've got a `newAction` with a form in Fluid and `createAction` which sends the data to a service, which sends it to the API. The DTO model has validation, which is handled correctly. If the form data isn't valid, the user is forwarded to the `newAction` correctly. However the data isn't filled into the form anymore. I've got a feeling I'm forgetting something small, but as far as I can see it should work.

My model looks like (simplified):

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\MyExtension\Controller;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation as Extbase;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Dto\Item;
use Vendor\MyExtension\Service\ItemService;

class MyController extends ActionController
{
    /**
     * @var ItemService
     */
    protected ItemService $itemService;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction(): void
    {
        $this->assign('items', $this->itemsService->getItems());
    }

    /**
     * @param Item $item
     * @return void
     * @Extbase\IgnoreValidation("service")
     */
    public function newAction(Item $item = null): void
    {
        $this->assign('item', $item);
    }

    /**
     * @param Item $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function createAction(Item $item): void
    {
        $this->itemService->add($item);

        $this->redirect('list');
    }
}
```

The DTO model looks like:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Dto;

class Item
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected string $value1;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Validate("NotEmpty")
     */
    protected string $value2;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue1(): string
    {
        return $this->value1;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value1
     */
    public function setValue1(string $value1): void
    {
        $this->value1 = $value1;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue2(): string
    {
        return $this->value2;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value2
     */
    public function setValue2(string $value2): void
    {
        $this->value2 = $value2;
    }
}
```

And the Fluid template for the form:

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers">
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="Content">
    <f:form action="create" method="post" object="{item}" name="item">
        <f:form.validationResults>
            <f:if condition="{validationResults.flattenedErrors}">
                <ul class="errors">
                    <f:for each="{validationResults.flattenedErrors}" as="errors" key="propertyPath">
                        <li>{propertyPath}
                            <ul>
                                <f:for each="{errors}" as="error">
                                    <li>{error.code}: {error}</li>
                                </f:for>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </f:for>
                </ul>
            </f:if>
        </f:form.validationResults>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="value1">Value 1</label>
            <f:form.textfield property="value1" id="value1" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="value2">Value 2</label>
            <f:form.textfield property="value2" id="value2" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </f:form>
</f:section>
</html>
```

If I debug `$item` in `newAction` it is always `null`, even after submitting the form with invalid data (empty `value2` field). It does show the expected validation result.

Comment: Since the validation fails, the data is not saved and therefore cannot be displayed again. I solve this with an additional JavaScript validation in the frontend. This way the data is not sent and remains displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't check everything client side with JavaScript. But it does work for the edit/update actions. When the validation fails, the edited data is not saved, but it is displayed in the form.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because you call a `$this->redirect('list')` in your code and `redirect()` calls a different action via 30x HTTP redirect that prevent the extbase persistence mechanism to be called.

When you call the `$this->itemService->add($item)`, your data are changed in memory but not persisted in database.

If you want to save the data in database, you have to call manually the `PersistenceManager` with :

```
$persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager::class);
$persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

But may be you can just replace the `redirect()` with a `forward()` and then the non-persisted changes will still be available and persisted with the next action call.

Comment: The problem is not with the redirect to the list after saving. It is saved using an external API, not in the database. The problem is with validation. If the data for `createAction` isn't valid, it automatically forwards back to `newAction`, showing the form with validation errors. It should show the data filled in by the user in the form, but it doesn't. It does work correctly for the `edit/updateAction`.